# Counting Semistandard Young Tableaux For Triangular Shapes?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, young-tableaux, oeis

If $k \leq n$ I denote the Young diagram with shape $(n,n-1,n-2,\ldots,1)$ by $\lambda^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}$. I write $f^{\lambda_n^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}}$ to count the number of semistandard Young tableaux with shape $\lambda^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}$ and maximum entry $n$. For example if $n=3$ then we draw: 
$\lambda^{3,2,1}=
        \begin{matrix}
        \bullet & \bullet & \bullet\\
        \bullet & \bullet & \\
        \bullet &  &  \\
        \end{matrix}$
and it can be shown that $f^{\lambda_{3}^{3,2,1}}=8.$ I can construct a sequence for $f^{\lambda_n^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}}$ starting with $n=1$ and it is $$1,2,8,64,1024,3278,\ldots$$ Inspection show this sequence appears to be
[A006125](https://oeis.org/A006125) modulo an offset of +1. If $(i,j)$ is any cell in $\lambda^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}$ and $h(i,j)$ and $j-i$ are the hook lengths and content of the cell respectively then we can use Stanley's content formula and write

$$\prod_{(i,j) \in \lambda^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}}{n+j-i\above 1.5pt
 h(i,j)}=2^{n(n-1)\above 1.5pt 2} $$

> **Question:** Let $\lambda^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}$ be a Young diagram with triangular shape and let $t_n={n(n-1)\above 1.5pt 2}.$ If $f^{\lambda_n^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}}$ counts the number of semistandard Young Tableaux of shape $\lambda^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}$ and maximum entry $n$ is it true $$f^{\lambda_n^{n,n-1,\ldots,1}}=2^{t_n}$$ ?

Comment: I might have the $j$ and the $i$ in the "content formula" switched the wrong way ?

Comment: this comes down to proving that $\frac{\prod _i^n \prod _j^{-i+n+1} (-i+j+n)}{\prod _k^n (2 k-1)^{-k+n+1}} = 2^{n(n-1)/2}$